# Python Mechanize with nested links

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

I am currently crawling a site with has many levels of links and it seems like mechanize cannot handle nested links. For example let's say I have:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open('some_site');

for link in br.links():
  br.follow_link(link)
  for link in br.links():
    br.follow_link(link)
```

Once mechanize got out of inner loop, it just stops there without looping through the links from outer loop.

I tried br.back() but it didn't work either. Is there a workaround for it or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: just a suggestion: try requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) will make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the links in a list before you start looping:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open('some_site');

current_links = list(br.links())

for link in current_links:
  br.follow_link(link)
  sub_links = list(br.links())
  for link in sub_links:
    br.follow_link(link)
```

As you change pages, the thing you are iterating over (`br.links()`) is changing, which is probably causing strange behaviour.

Comment: Yup looks like that's the issue. But you should edit your answer so that the list is copied by value. Otherwise sub_links still holds a reference back to br.links() and it won't work either.